# Script start with Docker Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to have a script for my projekt that starts everytime my container start or restart. The script should run in the console some statments like Console/cake schema etc.
I am using Cakephp 2.x for my projekt and docker.

I tried in the docker file with CMD oder ENTRYPOINT, but the process ends if the script is finished. My container stopped.

```
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/starter.sh"]
```

or

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/starter.sh"]
```

or

```
COPY starter.sh /
RUN chmod +x /starter.sh
```

With the first and second i get the script but the main prozess isnt running.

At the third try the script doesnt run, but my projekt runs.

Comment: Can you try to provide some logs ? With Kitematic or anything else. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> An ENTRYPOINT allows you to configure a container that will run as an executable.

And for CMD as well:

> The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing container. These defaults can include an executable, or they can omit the executable, in which case you must specify an ENTRYPOINT instruction as well.

So these are used for the main executable. So your third attempt was in the right direction, you only forgot one important step: Executing your script after making it executable with `chmod +x`

If you include another RUN statement like:

```
RUN /starter.sh
```

your script will run

Note what the documentation says about `RUN`:

> The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.

This means that it will cache the results of Run if docker does not see the results as different, which means that the script only runs whenever the image is created the first time or whenever your script changes. Most likely this is the behaviour that you want anyway, but you can run it without this caching behaviour:

> The cache for RUN instructions isn’t invalidated automatically during the next build. The cache for an instruction like RUN apt-get dist-upgrade -y will be reused during the next build. The cache for RUN instructions can be invalidated by using the --no-cache flag, for example docker build --no-cache.

I also suggest checking out the best practices for the `RUN` statement: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check out RUN and CMD in the manual. But I also notice that you said that the process stopped when your script finished. Are you sure that your script won't stop? If your process will stop then no matter what you do, the container will stop at the end.